# How do I create CiviEvents that occur in different timezones?

Tags: civievent, timezone, timestamp

Our site will be host to many different events. Some will happen in meatspace and others online. However, they will all have participants from different timezones or be based in different timezones.

For example, a regular Social Lunch in Adelaide, Australia, a regular Public Lecture in Melbourne Australia and a regular online committee meeting with participants from (at times) more than 5 different timezones.

The current situation with CiviCRM and events are that they are displayed as the raw date and time they were scheduled at and a lay person would assume it's their local time. When in actual fact, it's been scheduled at the timezone of the Drupal7 site (Australia/Adelaide).

This means though, that I cannot set an event for Melbourne Australia, set it to display the correct time the event is occurring in Melbourne and have the ical feed give the correct time. I either have to schedule it at the equivalent Adelaide time (so that the ical feed is correct) or schedule it as if it were Melbourne local time but have the ical feed giving the wrong time.

Is there already a fix for this? If not, my organisation would be willing to commit funding to this issue.

Comment: Hi Scott, was there any progress with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No existing fix I know of. It's maddening, and the prime example of this is civicrm.org! The site runs in US Pacific time, so when we have Washington, DC, meetups scheduled, the iCal has the wrong time.

Answer (score 2):

An issue has been created for a similar requirement: [CRM-17618 - time zone field needed for event creation](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17618). You could check whether the requirements described there cover your use case and see if there's scope for collaboration, joint funding etc.